# CSS margins not working in Chrome and Safari (works in Firefox)

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

I styles in the following class are not being applied properly in Chrome and Safari. It works fine in Firefox.

```
.miniatures{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

This is the site: http://abs.marcmorales.es/index.php?s=5&p=1&i=0

Answer (score 2):

Your #wrapper above has `margin-bottom: -30px;`. That's what's causing the overlap. Any reason why you have this? Take it out and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `overflow: hidden;` to your `#wrapper` div should do it.

Comment: Adding overflow: hidden; to your #wrapper div should do it.